# How do I put xml-nodesets (created with rvest) into a tibble using purrr's map-function in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest, xml2

I want to scrape a large amount of websites. For this, I first read in the websites' html-scripts and store them as xml_nodesets. As I only need the websites' contents, I lastly extract each websites' contents from the xml_nodesets. To achieve this, I have written following code:

```
# required packages
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
    
# urls of the example sources
test_files <- c("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping")
        
# reading in the html sources, storing them as xml_nodesets
test <- test_files %>% 
map(., ~ xml2::read_html(.x, encoding = "UTF-8"))
        
# extracting selected nodes (contents)
test_tbl <- test %>%
     map(., ~tibble(
     # scrape contents
     test_html = rvest::html_nodes(.x, xpath = '//*[(@id = "toc")]')  
            ))
```

Unfortunately, this produces following error:

```
Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `test_html` is a `xml_nodeset` object.
```

I think I understand the substance of this error, but I can't find a way around it. It's also a bit strange, because I was able to smoothly run this code in January and suddenly it is not working anymore. I suspected package updates to be the reason, but installing older versions of *xml2*, *rvest* or *tibble* didn't help either. Also, scraping only one single website doesn't produce any errors either:

```
test <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  rvest::html_nodes(xpath = '//*[(@id = "toc")]')
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this issue? Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** I removed `%>% html_text` from ...

```
test_tbl <- test %>%
     map(., ~tibble(
     # scrape contents
     test_html = rvest::html_nodes(.x, xpath = '//*[(@id = "toc")]')  
            ))
```

... as this doesn't produce this error. The edited code does, though.

Comment: Your code ran fine for me.purrr 0.3.4; dplyr 1.0.2; xml2 1.3.2; rvest 0.3.5; package ‘xml2’ was built under R version 4.0.3

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! You're right... I accidentally included html_text(), which indeed doesn't lead to this error. If I delete it (and my original code doesn't necessarily have this part, I edited my question...), it will produce the error described above. Do you have an idea why that is/how I can avoid it?

Comment: _`I lastly extract each websites' contents from the xml_nodesets`_ : Without `html_text` you aren't extracting the contents of the nodeset. You are simply trying to store the nodeset. Which did you intend? `%>%html_text` works. Also, the method call, I think, should be `html_node` in this instance as I expect a single node match.

Comment: I think I expressed myself a bit unclearly, sorry... in my original code it is indeed necessary to simply try storing the nodeset first, extracting the websites' contents using html_text happens at a later point (that's why I deleted that part, it doesn't produce an error). However, apparently only storing nodesets using map + tibble doesn't seem to work anymore, although I'm certain it used to a couple of months ago. The concrete method call doesn't seem to be issue here.

Comment: I had issues after saving/restoring this tibble. See solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69816202/save-xml-document-xml-node-object-in-a-tibble-for-mutating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the objects in a list.

```
test %>%
  purrr::map(~tibble(
    # scrape contents
    test_html = list(rvest::html_nodes(.x, xpath = '//*[(@id = "toc")]'))  
  ))

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  test_html 
#  <list>    
#1 <xml_ndst>

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  test_html 
#  <list>    
#1 <xml_ndst>
```