# Save `xml_document/xml_node` object in a tibble for mutating

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse

I would like to save a html page to a tibble so that I could later use mutate on the page content

I thought about reading the html direct to a tibble:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#does not work
tibble(html=read_html("https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=040445"))
#> Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
#> x Column `html` is a `xml_document/xml_node` object.
```

Reading as a `list` works:

```r
#works
works <- tibble(html=list(read_html("https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&ApplNo=040445")))
works
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   html      
#>   <list>    
#> 1 <xml_dcmn>
```

However, I cannot use `mutate` then:

```r
# does not work
works %>% 
  mutate(table=html_nodes(unlist(page),"#exampleApplSuppl"))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `table`.
#> i `table = html_nodes(unlist(page), "#examleApplSuppl")`.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Just if anybody uses this approach and wants to store the results. Once you reload this tibble from an .rds file, `html_nodes` will give you the error: `external pointer is not valid`. This is because external pointers are only stored in the memory. See solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261745/r-rvest-error-error-in-doc-namespacesdoc-external-pointer-is-not-valid/69824191#69824191)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the 'html' column is `list`, loop over the `list` and return the output in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
works %>% 
   mutate(table = map(html, ~ html_nodes(.x, "#examleApplSuppl")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  html       table     
  <list>     <list>    
1 <xml_dcmn> <xml_ndst>
```